# Как менять ссылку в боте?

Tags: python, aiogram, бот

Использую Python для создания бота на aiogram, есть кнопка 'url=ссылка'
Как я могу с помощью команды в боте поменять эту ссылку не меняя в коде?

Comment: хранить ссылку в базе данных и по команде вносить изменения в бд

Comment: когда юзер вставляет ссылку вы можете сохранить её в базу данных Sql записав туда ид юзера и ссылку, и так в любом момент сможете достать её

Comment: ссылка где?...если в отправленном сообщении, то чтобы его отредактировать нужен идентификатор пользователя и идентификатор сообщения